# Python Pandas - Move values down row on date conditional

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a column that moves `df.code` up one row only if:

- a) has a code other than Null/None, and:
- b) it is the previous day (i.e. 04-11, 04-12, not 04-20, 04-22)

  - (Notice that if rows are not two sequential dates, the code should not be moved back)

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2019-04-19','2019-04-20','2019-05-03', '2019-05-04',
             '2019-10-01','2019-10-07','2019-10-11', '2019-11-20'],
    'category': ['category A', 'category A', 'category A', 'category A',
             'category C', 'category C', 'category C', 'category C'],
    'code': ['None', 'None', 'None', '8008',
             'None', 'None', '9001', 'None']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)

date            category    code
0   2019-04-19  category A  None
1   2019-04-20  category A  None
2   2019-05-03  category A  None
3   2019-05-04  category A  8008
4   2019-10-01  category C  None
5   2019-10-07  category C  None
6   2019-10-11  category C  9001
7   2019-11-20  category C  None
```

Desired dataframe (edited):

```
date            category    code    new_code
0   2019-04-19  category A  None    0
1   2019-04-20  category A  None    0
2   2019-05-03  category A  None    8008
3   2019-05-04  category A  8008    0
4   2019-10-01  category C  None    0
5   2019-10-07  category C  None    0
6   2019-10-11  category C  9001    0
7   2019-11-20  category C  None    0
```

I've made several attempts, however this is the best approach, however it only creates T/F values and doesn't produce the best results.

```
tag_list = df['category'].unique()
bigdf = pd.DataFrame()
for t in tag_list:
  dumb = df[df['category'] == t]
  dumb['new code'] = dumb.code != dumb.code.shift()
  bigdf = bigdf.append(dumb)

date            category    code    new code
0   2019-04-19  category A  None    True
1   2019-04-20  category A  None    False
2   2019-05-03  category A  None    False
3   2019-05-04  category A  8008    True
4   2019-10-01  category C  None    True
5   2019-10-10  category C  None    False
6   2019-10-11  category C  9001    True
7   2019-11-20  category C  None    True
```

Comment: @smci:  I think we were editing this at the same time. I must have saved over your edits before you submitted them. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Starbucks: ok, no worries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using @QuangHoang start:

```
date_mask = (df.groupby('category')['date'].diff() == pd.Timedelta(days=1)).shift(-1).ffill()

df['new code'] = df['code'].replace('None',0)\
                           .groupby(df['category'])\
                           .shift(-1, fill_value=0)\
                           .where(date_mask, 0)
```

Output:

```
        date    category  code new code
0 2019-04-19  category A  None        0
1 2019-04-20  category A  None        0
2 2019-05-03  category A  None     8008
3 2019-05-04  category A  8008        0
4 2019-10-01  category C  None        0
5 2019-10-07  category C  None        0
6 2019-10-11  category C  9001        0
7 2019-11-20  category C  None        0
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like just `groupby().shift()`:

```
df['new_code'] = (df['code'].replace('None',0)
                      .groupby(df['category'])
                      .shift(-1, fill_value=0)
                 )
```

Output:

```
        date    category  code new_code
0 2019-04-19  category A  None        0
1 2019-04-20  category A  None        0
2 2019-05-03  category A  None     8008
3 2019-05-04  category A  8008        0
4 2019-10-01  category C  None        0
5 2019-10-10  category C  None     9001
6 2019-10-11  category C  9001        0
7 2019-11-20  category C  None        0
```

Comment: Hi Quang Hoang. This is a good answer, however this answer doesnt work with the second criteria always. There could be a code w/o a previous timestamp that is a day before. I edited my question to be a little more clearer. Thank you